# 95 confidence interval for data with a log trendline

Tags: confidence-interval

I have a data set which a logarithmic trendline fits and I am trying to create 95% confidence interval lines for the trendline. Any suggestions?

y = 0.1818 * ln(x) + 0.5268

X 
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
3
6
7
7
7
29
2
5
1
1
1.5
1.5

Y
0.7577
0.7174
0.8109
0.0918
0.3988
0.5531
0.5407
0.3541
0.9979
0.9896
0.9602
0.6384
0.8911
0.9941
1
0.7716
0.1981
0.2481
0.5943
0.7931